# $\delta - \epsilon$ argument

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=1/x^2$. Use a $\delta - \epsilon$  argument to prove that for each $x \neq 0$, the quotient $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ converges to $-2x^{-3}$ as $h \to 0$.

Can some explain a sketch of the proof and what does it mean to use a $\delta - \epsilon$  argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
You need to prove the following, $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ there exists $\delta(\epsilon,x) > 0 $ such that 
$$ |h|< \delta \implies \Big| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} + \frac{2}{x^3} \Big|< \epsilon .$$